# How to show a loading image while a process takes place in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I add a "loading" image to the following code. Here is what I mean. If I add a button to this code and the user clicks it. The content from the php file will load in the div with an id of "notifications" but while the php file is processing I want to show a loading image. I will get an image from this website `http://www.ajaxload.info/`

```
function onSuccess(data, status) {
    data = $.trim(data);
    $("#notification").html(data);
}

function onError(data, status) {
    // handle an error
}        

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var formData = $("#expander").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "grab.php",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var $loader = $('<div />').attr('id', 'loader');
var $spinner = $('<img />').attr('src', 'ajax-loader.gif')
    .attr('alt', 'Loading');
$loader.append($spinner);
$('body').children().last().after($loader);
$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
       $loader.show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $loader.hide();
    });
```

Comment: each time i press the button it adds a new loading image is there a way to only make it show one image even when i press the button multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

u can achieve it like this :

create a div with id loadingImg, place your loading GIF there
with the use of jQuery's .ajaxStart u can detect the start of an ajax request.
Fade in your preloading image and fade it out if the function returns success.

You can attach the .ajaxStart event to any element, I use the preloading image container to make it a bit more noticeable.

[.ajaxStart() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

```
function onSuccess(data, status) {
    data = $.trim(data);
    $('#loadingImg').fadeOut();
    $("#notification").html(data);
}

function onError(data, status) {
    // handle an error
}        

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var formData = $("#expander").serialize();

        $('#loadingImg').ajaxStart(function (){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "grab.php",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```